# How to ignore a folder when sending a pull request to parent from a fork

Tags: git, github

We have forked a git public project into our local git repo. We have to add a folder to the forked project so as to make it work with our home grown continuous integration system. But we don't want these company specific files to be part of the pull request when we contribute back into the public repo. Does github support this kind of flow? We could think of a couple of solutions, but none of them seemed elegant. Has anyone been in this situation? What was your solution?

Thanks !

PS: Relatively new to Git, so I might not have searched with the right search terms. Apologies if this question was already asked and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. You'll need to keep your company specific changes on one branch(A) and the changes you want to contribute back to upstream on another(B).

Then send pull requests from B back to upstream/master. A pull request is a request to pull one more "commits". There's no file level granularity unless you craft the commits appropriately.

Comment: Ah.. That is the solution we are going towards, but it just seemed a bit round about to me.  I guess we might have to write a script to merge from A->B automatically (excluding the  unwanted files) Thank you for your reply !

Comment: No. You should develop the changes you want to upstream on `B`. Then regularly merge those into `A` (where you do your extra work). Never merge from A->B. That would be the right way.